# Unable to show values in Pop Up Dialog in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am showing data in a datatable in primefaces.I have 5 columns.In last column i am showing Edit & Delete button.On click of edit button i am showing the dialog popup but i am not able to display the data of selected row in popup dialog?

Code of xhtml

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Sale Item</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen"
        type="text/css" />

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable var="transection" value="#{trans.getTransections()}"
            paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            paginatorPosition="bottom">
            <p:column headerText="number">
                <h:outputText value="#{transection.number}" />

            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Amount" width="200">
                <h:outputText value="#{transection.amount}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Type" width="200">
                <h:outputText value="#{transection.type}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Date/Time" width="200">
                <h:outputText value="#{transection.date}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Action" width="200">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0">
                    <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('TransDialog').show()"
                        icon="edit-icon">

                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transection}"
                            target="#{trans.selectedTrans}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage value="images/delete.png"></p:graphicImage>
                    </p:commandLink>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:dialog header="Transection Detail" widgetVar="TransDialog"
            resizable="false" width="400" showEffect="explode"
            hideEffect="explode">

            <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Number:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{trans.selectedTrans.number}"/> 

                <h:outputText value="Amount:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{trans.selectedTrans.amount}"/> 

                <h:outputText value="Type:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{trans.selectedTrans.type}"/> 
            </p:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid style="margin:0 auto" columns="1">
            <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="#{trans.printcal()}"></p:commandButton>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Code of ManagedBean

```
   package com.loteria.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.loteria.beans.Transection;
import com.loteria.model.DBaction;
import com.loteria.util.Util;
@ManagedBean(name="trans")
@SessionScoped
public class TransController {

    ArrayList<Transection> list;
    public ArrayList<Transection> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Transection> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    private Transection selectedTrans;

    public Transection getSelectedTrans() {
        return selectedTrans;
    }

    public void setSelectedTrans(Transection selectedTrans) {
        this.selectedTrans = selectedTrans;
    }

    public ArrayList<Transection> getTransections()
    {
    list=new ArrayList<Transection>();
         DBaction db=new DBaction();
         HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
         int uid=Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("uid").toString());
         list=db.getAllTransections(uid);
         return list;

    }
    public void printcal()
    {
        System.out.print("princal");
    System.out.print("num is:"+selectedTrans.number);
        System.out.print("amount is"+selectedTrans.amount);
        System.out.print("type is"+selectedTrans.type);

    }
}
```

Codce of bean calss

```
   package com.loteria.beans;

public class Transection
{

    public String amount;
    public String number;
    public String date;
    public String type;
    public String status;
    public String tran_num;

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getTran_num() {
        return tran_num;
    }
    public void setTran_num(String tran_num) {
        this.tran_num = tran_num;
    }



}
```

I get exception

**javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /User/Records.xhtml @63,57 value="#{trans.selectedTrans.number}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedTrans' returned null**

Comment: Works great in the Primefaces showcases. Find the differences

Comment: Oh and make your getTransactions() lazy…  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: Use debug for sure the `public void setSelectedTrans(Transection selectedTrans)` receive not null value

Comment: In addition to the accessor method strategy, 1) I would choose `dynamic="true"` (`<p:dialog>`). 2) You also need `update=":form1:display"` (the `<p:commandBtton>` showing the `<p:dialog>`). 3) Since you need to submit the components held by the mentioned `<p:dialog>`, you need to enclose them inside another `<h:form>` - needless to say, "*without nesting `<h:form>`*". 4) You apparently do not need a verbose session scoped managed in this case. A view scoped bean is much more sufficient to handle this kind of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TechGuy, the `p:dialog` is rendered on page load even if it's not immediately visible to the user (check the HTML source). This means that `selectedTrans` is null when the page is first rendered, resulting in a PropertyNotFoundException. You should be able to fix this error simply by initializing the field in the backing-bean:

```
private Transection selectedTrans = new Transection();
```

This will be overwritten by the `setPropertyActionListener` when you click the button, which is good.

Comment: I did this & got solution thanks.